# How multiply Blocked Matrices?

Tags: matrices

I am having a hard time understanding how to multiply blocked matrices with rectangle matrices and blocking into non-square matrices. Can someone please explain me how that works?

Comment: Block matrix multiplication works just like regular matrix multiplication.  And you can block a matrix however you want.

Comment: Can you explain more with a general formula? An example too would be very helpful please.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Mathematics SE! A few tips/suggestions: Be more specific, and give some examples; let us know what you have tried yourself; and do some research on your own first. Perhaps this thread may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787909/block-matrix-multiplication .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can help you

**Example:**

$A=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 3  & 2\\
        4 & 1  & 3\\
        3 & 2  & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$\to$
$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      2&3&2\\
      4&1&3 \\
\hline
      3 &2 &1
    \end{array}
\right] $

$ B=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3 \\
        2 & 4 \\
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$\to$
$ \left[
    \begin{array}{}
      1&3\\
      2&4 \\
\hline
      2 &1 
    \end{array}
\right] $

$AB= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
        A_{11} & A_{12} \\
        A_{21} & A_{22} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times\begin{bmatrix}
        B_{1}  \\
        B_{2}  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        A_{11}B_{1} + A_{12}B_{2} \\
        A_{21}B_{1} + A_{22}B_{2} \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A_{11}B_{1}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         2 & 3 \\
        4 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3  \\
        2 & 4  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        8 & 18 \\
        6 & 16 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A_{12}B_{2}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         2  \\
        3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2 \\
        6 & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A_{21}B_{1}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         3 & 2 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 3  \\
        2 & 4  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        7 & 17 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A_{22}B_{2}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
\times\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

---

$A_{11}B_{1}+A_{12}B_{2}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         8 & 18 \\
        6 & 16 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
        4 & 2  \\
        6 & 3  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        12 & 20 \\
        12 & 19 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$A_{21}B_{1}+A_{22}B_{2}= 
        \begin{bmatrix}
         7 & 17 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
+\begin{bmatrix}
        2 & 1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
        9 & 18 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

$$AB=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        12 & 20  \\
        12 & 19  \\
\hline
        9 & 18  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: This is what I needed to see to understand it. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome :)